# SQLite Database taking too much time to retrieve (or fetch some data)

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, ios5

I have a sqlite cipher database with around 80000 records (containing 7 columns). Its currently taking too much time in searching the records. I need an optimized way of searching for 1 or more record based on some criteria (need something like indexing) so that I can reduce the searching time. Does anybody has any idea about how to proceed to achieve this? Need help urgently. :(

EDITED:
I am using sqlite cipher API because I need to store the encrypted data in sqlite database. I have set the pragma key and the encryption being used is AES - 256. I have also created the index on each table in my database. But my searching is not fast. Its taking too much time. Need to solve this ASAP.

2nd TIME EDITED:
Hey guys, I am badly stuck this time. I am making a search as soon as user clicks on a text field. To summarize the problem, let me tell you the flow.

I have 2 text fields and a table containing ~80k records and 7 columns.
When I type anything in the field1, a search is made onto the table with the content of the field1. So lets say I type 'a' in my field1, then a select query returns all the records containing 'a' letter in column1. So, the table is being searched as soon as I type the letters.
Uptill now there is no problem. Its returning the records without any time delay. The query is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT <COL1> COLLATE NOCASE as <COL1> from <TABLE_NAME> where <COL1> like '%ab%'   LIMIT 0,501
```

Now, if I click on field 2, then I see the cursor on field2 after 1 secs as this query gets execute:

```
SELECT DISTINCT <COL2> COLLATE NOCASE as <COL2> from <TABLE_NAME> where <COL1> like '%ab%'   LIMIT 0,501
```

Now, the db fetching process is taking time if I type anything on field2. Here is the final query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT <COL2> COLLATE NOCASE as <COL2> from <TABLE_NAME> where <COL1> like '%ab%' AND <COL2> like '%cd%'  LIMIT 0,501
```

When I tried to analyse the problem, I came to know that the problem is due to DISTINCT Keyword.
I have created indices on the columns as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX <name1> on <TABLE_NAME>(<COL1>)
CREATE INDEX <name2> on <TABLE_NAME>(<COL1> COLLATE CASE)
CREATE INDEX <name3> on <TABLE_NAME>(<COL2>)
CREATE INDEX <name4> on <TABLE_NAME>(<COL2> COLLATE CASE)
```

Anyone has any idea how to make this retrieval fast.

Comment: maybe the problem not in the sqlite size, but your sql statement. you want to post your sql statement here?

Comment: The query is something like [@"select rowid from `%@` where \"Values\" = '%@'", tableName, descValue] where descValue is the col value for col "Values"

Comment: what is the returnType of the function? Always try to return the class object.

Comment: Is the order of your columns in while you created index and the order of columns when you retrieves the result is same. The order is an important factor for lookup.

Answer (score 2):

Something like indexing? SQLite is fully capable of using indexes, [as explained here in the docs.](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) The structure and purpose of your tables will determine how best to implement them, though.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use the SQLite amalgamation source. If you need full text search too, you can add this define on top of `sqlite3.c` (or what values do you need searchable?).

```
#define SQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3
```

Then create an index using the [docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createindex.html) **VeryVito** mentioned.

Comment: Hey Erik, have doubts in using FTS3 Enabled SQLite. As this link suggests, [SQLITE FTS3](http://sqlite.org/fts3.html) I can reduce the database fetch time significantly (from 22 seconds to 0.003 seconds) if I use FTS3 or FTS4 Extensions. I want to know how to use this extensions and also the difference between this and the ordinary sqlite table in terms of queries and data storage. I am already using sqlite database, but since the records are around 80000, so I want to use FTS3 now. What changes will I need to make to migrate to fts3.?

Comment: I've currently an app deployed using FTS3 with around 90000 records and the full text search time is usually around 1 or 2ms. I can't help you with your migration issue.

Comment: I am using sqlite cipher API because I need to store the encrypted data in sqlite database. I have set the pragma key. and the encryption being used in AES - 256. I have also created the index on each table in my database. But my searching is not fast. Its taking too much time. Maybe now you can help me as I am already using the sqlite cipher API. Pls buddy. Seriously need your help Erik.

Comment: Sorry I'm not a DB expert. Just gave you the FTS hint because I recently used it myself. Add this to your question, so others can help you out.